# How to compute standard errors for Blanchard-Quah-restricted SVAR?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, time-series, structural-estimation

People tell me that the way of bootstrapping standard errors in the original paper is incorrect, but then how should I do it?

Is there a convention of how to compute standard errors for Blanchard-Quah type SVAR in the literature?